# Why use <ion-input> instead of <input>

Tags: ionic-framework

What is the reasoning behind using a `<ion-input>` instead of just a normal `<input>` element?

This question also regards using Ionic components in general. Why not just use my own components? I am aware that Ionic have different styles for some of the components, but if I want a same looking input on both android and ios, then couldn't I just use a normal `<input>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic framework itself is a library of rich UI components, which unifies development experience by making codebase: `platform agnostic`. So developers can focus on one code base, Ionic component takes care of adapting its look to the native platform. Ionic components natively provide `rich UI`, `platform continuity`, `easy navigation & event handling`, `native access` & `theming`.

You can read more in detail [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/concepts).

Developers choose Ionic framework in **technology stack** so one don't have to write custom styling/code for each platform.

Instead if you are using basic `html tags`, then you are even better off putting Ionic in your technology stack as you are just reinventing the wheel & writing custom code for each platform (iOS, Android, Electron, Browser, Mobile, Tablet) for styling & event hanling.

Answer (score 0):

**UI Components**

For those completely new to Ionic app development, it can be helpful to get a high-level understanding of the core `philosophy, concepts, and tools behind the project`. Before diving into complex topics, we'll cover the basics of what Ionic Framework is, and how it works.

> UI Components

**Ionic Framework is a library of UI Components**, which are reusable elements that serve as the building blocks for an application. Ionic Components are built with web standards using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. Though the components are

> pre-built, they're designed from the ground up to be highly
>   customizable so apps can make each component their own, allowing each
>   app to have its own look and feel.

More specifically, Ionic components can be easily themed to globally change appearance across an entire app.

**customizing the look, please see Theming.**